# How to prevent repeated value from the randomised results?

Tags: excel, vba

I used the VBA to randomise a list of samples, but the result shows that some of them are repeated, I want to have the result that are not repeated, is anyone can help? thanks

I want to generate the randomised result from the total number (Cell E2) based on how many samples (Cell F2) are required, shows the results from F4 and to below but without repeated items, thanks

[image: Picture of repeated items]

```
Sub Randomise_data()

'step 1: clear list
    Range("F4:G4").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("F2").Select

'step 2: Draw randomised sample from the total number

    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    
    Range("F2").Select
    
    Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
        i = ActiveCell.Value                'the number of times required to be drawn
        j = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value      'the total number
        
        For k = 1 To i
            ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Value = Int(j * Rnd) + 1    '(2 is put to second row for first item)
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select          '(1 is move to 1 cell below for second item)
        Next k
        
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, -1).Select      'final cursor move to which cell, -1 is to the left column
    Loop
    
    Range("F2").Select
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Randomize Data

```
Sub RandomizeData()

    Const MIN_VAL As Long = 1

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    Dim MaxVal As Long: MaxVal = ws.Range("E2").Value
    Dim SampleSize As Long: SampleSize = ws.Range("F2").Value
    
    Dim tData(): tData = ws.Evaluate("ROW(" & MIN_VAL & ":" & MaxVal & ")")
    
    ShuffleColumn tData
    
    Dim dData(): ReDim dData(1 To SampleSize, 1 To 1)
    
    Dim r As Long
    
    For r = 1 To SampleSize
        dData(r, 1) = tData(r, 1)
    Next r
    
    With ws.Range("F4").Resize(SampleSize)
        .Value = dData
        .Resize(ws.Rows.Count - SampleSize - .Row + 1).Offset(SampleSize).Clear
    End With
    
End Sub

Sub ShuffleColumn(ByRef Data As Variant)
    
    Dim LB As Long: LB = LBound(Data, 1)
    
    Dim Temp As Variant, i As Long, j As Long
    
    For i = UBound(Data, 1) To LB + 1 Step -1
        j = Int((i - LB + 1) * Rnd + LB)
        Temp = Data(i, 1): Data(i, 1) = Data(j, 1): Data(j, 1) = Temp
    Next i

End Sub
```